Why my inheritance is not getting green? Such as CharacterManager class, which is another script
So here's my problem, I'm not getting promts or green text but the code works as intended.
I upgraded from Win10 to 11 a few weeks ago and this started to happen.. At first, I just thought it could be my bad, making a bad reference to classes and properties but it's not.
I tested enough to ensure myself it's just an extension missing or something, but to be honest I keep all as vanilla as possible.
Just in case im' using Unity.
I tried just running the code and it works as intended.
Also tried to get suggestions of possible correct references but I'm not getting any (I insist on this, the code works just fine)
Theese references should be Green:
InstantCharacterEffect
CharacterManager
and whilst typing, I should be able to TAB to get te rest of the reference writen by itself.

Open the package manager: Window -> Package Manager.
If you are using Visual Studio, make sure you have Visual Studio Editor installed.
If you are using VSCode, make sure you have Visual Studio Code Editor installed.
To install, open the package manager and make sure you are viewing the unity registry.

Scroll down to the above mentioned package for your code editor and install it.
In the preferences, Edit -> Preferences.. select the tab labeled External Tools on the left and make sure your code editor is selected in the dropdown in the top right.
Then click the Regenerate project files button to regenerate the project files for you code editor.

You are just awesome, I'm new around here and I love this community already. Many thanks m8, blessings.
